# Grouping list of listings by chapter name

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, koma-script

I want to write the chapter names to my LOF, LOT, and LOL to make them easier to read and found the following peace of code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258226/142122)

```
%%%%% from http://www.komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070 (Markus Kohm)
\makeatletter
\let\chapterhas@original@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\chapterhas{\thechapter}{#1}}%
  \chapterhas@original@addcontentsline{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterhas}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{chapterhas@#1@#2}{true}%
}
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}%
  \if@chaptertolists
    \doforeachtocfile{%
      \iftocfeature{\@currext}{chapteratlist}{%
        \ifundefinedorrelax{chapterhas@\thechapter @\@currext}{%
        }{%
          \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{chapteratlist}[{#1}]{#2}%
        }%
      }{}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{float@addtolists}{}{\scr@float@addtolists@warning}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
%%%%
```

It works perfectly fine for the LOF and the LOT but it won't work for the LOL. Im using the package `listings` to generate my listings, could that be a problem?
Here is a complete example, showing the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,toc=bibliography,toc=listof,chapteratlists=entry]{scrbook}

\AfterTOCHead[lof]{\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}}
\AfterTOCHead[lot]{\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}}

%%%%% from http://www.komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070 (Markus Kohm)
\makeatletter
\let\chapterhas@original@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\chapterhas{\thechapter}{#1}}%
  \chapterhas@original@addcontentsline{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterhas}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{chapterhas@#1@#2}{true}%
}
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}%
  \if@chaptertolists
    \doforeachtocfile{%
      \iftocfeature{\@currext}{chapteratlist}{%
        \ifundefinedorrelax{chapterhas@\thechapter @\@currext}{%
        }{%
          \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{chapteratlist}[{#1}]{#2}%
        }%
      }{}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{float@addtolists}{}{\scr@float@addtolists@warning}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
%%%%

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 3}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 1}]
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 2}]
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 3}]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Working list of tables]
[image: non functional list of listings]

So in short: How can I make the chapter name appear on the list of listings as they do on the list of tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code of yours, the following happens: The KOMA class macro `\doforeachtocfile` calls all registered list files, checks whether they have the property `chapteratlist`, and then writes the section entry to the respective list file. The `listings` package doesn't, however, register the list of listings with the KOMA class. But you can easily supply that. Just add:

- `\addtotoclist{lol}` to add the list of listings to the list of lists,
- `\setuptoc{lol}{chapteratlist}` to add the property `chapteratlist` to the list of listings.

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,toc=bibliography,toc=listof,chapteratlists=entry]{scrbook}

\AfterTOCHead[lof]{\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}}
\AfterTOCHead[lot]{\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}}

\addtotoclist{lol}
\setuptoc{lol}{chapteratlist}

%%%%% from http://www.komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070 (Markus Kohm)
\makeatletter
\let\chapterhas@original@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\chapterhas{\thechapter}{#1}}%
  \chapterhas@original@addcontentsline{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterhas}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{chapterhas@#1@#2}{true}%
}
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}%
  \if@chaptertolists
    \doforeachtocfile{%
      \iftocfeature{\@currext}{chapteratlist}{%
        \ifundefinedorrelax{chapterhas@\thechapter @\@currext}{%
        }{%
          \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{chapteratlist}[{#1}]{#2}%
        }%
      }{}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{float@addtolists}{}{\scr@float@addtolists@warning}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
%%%%

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 3}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 1}]
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 2}]
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 3}]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

KOMA-Script also provides package `scrhack` that improves several other packages, e.g., patches `listings` to use `tocbasic`. If you use this package, `chapteratlists=entry` automatically also works for `\listoflistings`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,toc=bibliography,toc=listof,chapteratlists=entry]{scrbook}

\AfterTOCHead[lof]{\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}}
\AfterTOCHead[lot]{\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}}

%%%%% from http://www.komascript.de/comment/5070#comment-5070 (Markus Kohm)
\makeatletter
\let\chapterhas@original@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\chapterhas{\thechapter}{#1}}%
  \chapterhas@original@addcontentsline{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterhas}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{chapterhas@#1@#2}{true}%
}
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}%
  \if@chaptertolists
    \doforeachtocfile{%
      \iftocfeature{\@currext}{chapteratlist}{%
        \ifundefinedorrelax{chapterhas@\thechapter @\@currext}{%
        }{%
          \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{chapteratlist}[{#1}]{#2}%
        }%
      }{}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{float@addtolists}{}{\scr@float@addtolists@warning}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
%%%%

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{scrhack}% use tocbasic for \listoflistings (and more)
\AfterTOCHead[lol]{\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 3}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 1}]
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 2}]
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing 3}]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]